# Is there a way to shorten these commands so that I don't have to give the list.add repeatedly (for each owner)?

Tags: java, inheritance

The vehicle() class is a superclass as you can see in the code. I want to keep 2 separate classes(at least that's what I think is the most efficient way. Please point out if I'm going the reverse way here!), one for vehicles and one for vehicleOwners, where owners' vehicles are also listed in vehicle() class. Basically, I'm going to put console input to search owners using their unique ownerId and also displaying various information fields(like mpg, top speed, resell value based on purchase date etc.) about their type of vehicle. I want to use efficient coding practices and adding each object item to the list looks a little awkward to me. Is there a different way out?

below is my vehicleOwner class

```
public class VehicleOwner extends Vehicle{

    private int yearsOwned;
    private String ownerName;
    private int ownerId;

    public VehicleOwner(String ownerBrand, String ownerModelNo,int ownerModelYear, int yearsOwned, String ownerName, int ownerId) {
        super(ownerBrand, ownerModelNo, ownerModelYear);

        this.yearsOwned = yearsOwned ;
        this.ownerName = ownerName;
        this.ownerId = ownerId;

        ArrayList<VehicleOwner> list = new ArrayList<VehicleOwner>();
        VehicleOwner owner1 = new VehicleOwner("Volvo", "XC60", 2014, 3, "Mary", 00011);
        VehicleOwner owner2 = new VehicleOwner("Subaru", "crosstrek", 2015, 2, "John", 00012);
        VehicleOwner owner3 = new VehicleOwner("Mercedes", "Eseries", 2016, 1, "Brandon", 00013);
        list.add(owner1);
        list.add(owner2);
        list.add(owner3);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way you can "shorten" this code is add new objects without creating variables for them:

```
list.add(new VehicleOwner("Volvo", "XC60", 2014, 3, "Mary", 00011));
list.add(new VehicleOwner("Subaru", "crosstrek", 2015, 2, "John", 00012));
list.add(new VehicleOwner("Mercedes", "Eseries", 2016, 1, "Brandon", 00013));
```

Comment: Of course :) Sorry, I'm new to both this language as well as SO!

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`Arrays.asList(T...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList-T...-) and remove the local references and please program to the `List` interface. Something like

```
List<VehicleOwner> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList( //
        new VehicleOwner("Volvo", "XC60", 2014, 3, "Mary", 00011), //
        new VehicleOwner("Subaru", "crosstrek", 2015, 2, "John", 00012), //
        new VehicleOwner("Mercedes", "Eseries", 2016, 1, "Brandon", 00013) //
));
```

Comment: Which is less efficient that adding items directly into list, as it involves several unnecessary operations (new array creation, new List from array creation, copying this items from this list to second list).

Comment: @Andremoniy True. But it doesn't call `list.add` repeatedly (or at all). Also, there are three elements. Let's not prematurely optimize.